# Are Beacons monitoring and ranging callbacks received in same BLE scans

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

From what I understand monitoring provides you information when a region has become visible in the vicinity of your scans (with callbacks like regionentered, regionexit etc) and then ranging gives your information about beacons in that region.

So behind the screen is same bluetooth scan sufficient to call both callbacks? Or we need to start separate scans for each?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, one scan is enough for doing all these. The scan callback provides enough information to calculate beacon region/ranges. (You can use libraries or write your own algorithm for these.)

However practically the app need to restart separate scans, just to protect the Bluetooth stack on your device. There are quite some device specific issues if you run one Bluetooth scan for long time. Restarting scan periodically will improve the stability significantly on some devices.

Comment: I did not quite get the restart scan part. It would be great if you could elaborate more on it. And assuming this is for android only since in iOS we cannot do ranging until monitoring callback is received?